# All items in if statement not firing

Tags: c#, if-statement, timer, messagebox

I'm trying to figure out why only the first line within the if statement is the only line being executed.

```
bool messageDisplayed = false;

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var position = axVLCPlugin21.input.Position;

    label1.Text = string.Format("{0}% completed", position * 100);

    if (position > 0.8 && messageDisplayed == false)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("80 has been passed");
        messageDisplayed = true;
    }
}
```

The messagebox kept showing up constantly, leading me to believe `messageDisplayed = true` was never being set, so I set a break point to check.

And sure enough, it enters the if statement, shows the messagebox, and then restarts the event- without ever going to `messageDisplayed = true;`

Is anyone able to see if I'm going wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MessageBox.Show()` "pauses" the execution of the code. `messageDisplayed = true;` is triggered when you close the `MessageBox`.

Consequently, modify your code as follows:

```
if (position > 0.8 && !messageDisplayed)
{
    messageDisplayed = true;
    MessageBox.Show("80 has been passed");
}
```

Comment: Please `!messageDisplayed` instead of `messageDisplayed == false`

Answer (score 0):

MessageBox causes a pause in running, which lets you event fired again, even before your bool variable become true. Try to put your bool before messagebox